How to distort a square waveform to get even harmonics?
I'm using a microcontroller with internal 12 bit DAC (buffered output, capable of 0-3.3 V) to produce an analog output consisting of variable amplitude square waves (0-270 mV) at a narrow audio frequency range (about 200 Hz to 3 kHz). This is a scope example of what the analog output looks like in the simplest case.

It is possible that multiple frequencies with different amplitude are digitally mixed together so the output can look more complex and the voltage can reach up to 3.3 V, and this is how it would look:

I only get odd harmonics on the output, obviously.
What I'm trying to achieve is something like this.  This is the output scope of an analog square wave signal (0-9 V) going through a NPN transistor VCA modulated by a variable voltage to alter the output amplitude.

the schematic looks like this:

I noticed that this signal is rich of even harmonics, even though the input signal is a square waves like mine. I noticed that this distortion (that I guess comes from the transistor) remains rather constant at different frequencies and different amplitudes.
So to mimic that and to introduce even harmonics in the spectrum, I tried to alter the width of the pulses of my digital square waves, and the result is acceptable, but there is still quite of a difference.
I could code a DDS oscillator instead of using naive square waves, but then I would need to update my microcontroller to something more capable.
So I'm wondering if there is a way to distort the waveform in the analog domain.
I tried to use a transistor like on the previous schematic, but I didn't get anything good from that, probably because the voltages levels are different (but mostly because I'm a programmer and my electronics/transistors knowledge is close to zero).
Please note that in this board I have at my disposal only +3.3V and +5V supplies.

If you already have an MCU, you should solve this digitally. Start with a waveform that already has both even and odd harmonics, a sawtooth wave. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave

Don't think you'll need to implement a DDS – why ot simply implement a sufficiently simplified simulation of the transistor circuit, which you apply to your pulse train in software?

A 50% duty cycle square wave will have no even harmonics, as you've noticed.
Passing the signal through a linear filter will not restore harmonics that are not there, for instance a lowpass filter.
Passing the signal through memoryless analogue distortion will not alter the symmetry of the pulses that ensures no even harmonics, for instance time varying gain that's substantially constant for the duration of a pulse.
The transistor circuit you have shown has memory AND non-linearity, and you can see the resulting loss of symmetry in the output pulses, which re-introduces the even harmonics. A simple alternative circuit to break the pulse symmetry would be a monostable, that emits a short pulse when triggered.
If you have control over how the signal is generated, then the simplest way to control which harmonics are and are not generated is to use a pulse waveform, where you control the duty cycle. As you have seen, 50% duty cycle creates no even harmonics, none of the form 2n. A 33.3% duty cycle will create no 3n harmonics, a 10% duty cycle creates no 10n harmonics. You will get the largest number of harmonics from a narrow pulse waveform, which is also unfortunately the one with the lowest output power. An alternative waveform is a sawtooth, which you can also regard as the narrow pulse waveform integrated. This integration gives you a 20 dB per octave fall in the power of the harmonics as their harmonic number rises.

To get all of the even harmonics of the square wave's base frequency, a solution that is very rich in those harmonics is a saw-tooth wave at twice the frequency of the square wave. This can be accomplished with some fairly simple circuits. I would post one now, but I am on my phone, so can't create a schematic.

You are correct in using a common emitter amplifier to create 2nd harmonics. This stems from the square law effect of Ic from small modulations of Vbe.
The current increases with Vbe and this causes the inverted output gain to be higher for positive sine inputs than the opposite.  This is the cause for all transistor distortion and why designs that try to prevent, and utilize CC bias, with low stage gain or high gain with negative feedback to minimize the Vbe variation and thus distortion.
I have discovered that the %THD is very close to the ratio of the gain differences for Vpk {+/-} / mean gain.
The fault in your analysis is using square wave audio (Class D) and assuming the duty cycle is 50% which is only true for null phase modulation.  Yet almost 100% modulation (m) and duty factor (d.f.) include all even and odd harmonics almost equally)
 sim
Let's consider a high gain Class A "H bias", commonly known to have high THD.
H bias has THD that increases from AC gain and output swing from square law effects on Vbe. So if you like 2nd harmonic distortion use a large swing with H bias and high gain (>50).
Saturation & clipping mainly increases odd harmonics, if symmetrical.  Making it asymmetrical increases all harmonics to some ratio.

My Falstad sim. design shows Rc/Re=100 with hFE=100 and Av= 63. The lower gain text results removed emitter bypass 100R and cap. with Rc/Re=10.

You can still get 2nd harmonics added to a square wave if you know how to design and analyze it. However, for a 1Vrms = +/-1Vpp square wave, it has the following spectral levels;
1f=  +2.10 dB   ( yes the sine has a greater peak than +/-  sq wave)
3f=  -7.44 dB or ~ -10 dB down
5f= -11.88 dB or ~ -24 dB down
To get the 2nd harmonic, (2f) equal to 3f, the distortion from the hardware of an NPN common emitter non-linear amplifier is exactly as you have done or use the amplifier's transfer function to simulate it.
Since your signal is a complex ramp of this fixed amplitude saturated signal, the variable gain transfer function of the VCA can also be simulated in firmware.
However, if you want a ramp signal with an edge, use a sawtooth waveform by formula, a lookup table or hardware. This gives a greater 2nd harmonic than the exponential ramp.


My Falstad SIM
